# Trying to use WEB API based library(CPR) in my application but Error while compiling <cpr/cpr.h> library in CLR project using visual c++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, clr, webapi

Like:-

"std" has no member "mutex"
"std" has no member "condition_variable"
"mutex" undefined
"cv_status" undefined

///////////////////
How to solve this..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a minimum example code which shows us your issues.

Comment: just after writing #include<cpr/cpr.h> the errors occur.

Comment: Im having the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: I think This is due to CLR Support... CPR is a native core c++ lib ,so it can't be compiled through CLR instructions. To use it try with native c++ frameworks like MFC or others.